# How to implement FlatList item counter

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm filtering a FlatList in renderItem(). I'm checking for a property and if it exists I render the item. I'd like to implement a counter so I know how many items I'm rendering, but if I try to set state from renderItem that makes an infinite loop and the app crashes. How can I best implement the counter? Do I need to filter the data before it gets to the render and increment the counter from the filter function?

```js
  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    let categoryIds = map(item.locations[0].categories, 'categoryId');
    if (selectedCatId === -1 || categoryIds.includes(selectedCatId)) {
      // setCounter(counter+1) // can't do this
      return (
        <StoreListItem
          tenant={item}
          navigation={navigation}
          showLocation={showLocation}
        />
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you need to show the counter on a UI somewhere ?

Comment: Why do you need a state variable for that counter? Just use a normal instance variable instead (`let countedItems = ...` or `this.countedItems = ...`)? It's still just JS, don't use state for something that isn't state (e.g. something that doesn't warrant a UI update).

Comment: @NisanthReddy Yes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's a functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this in your component:

```
const renderedItems = itemsToRender.map(renderItem).filter(x => x)
return <div>
  Total items: {renderedItems.length}
  Here they are:
  {renderedItems}
</div>
```

`.filter(x => x)` will filter out items that are `undefined` (an item will be undefined when your `renderItem` doesn't return a value, basically when the condition in your `if` is false)

Also don't forget to set `key` on `StoreListItem` inside your `renderItem`